# Restriction of a distribution over the cube $Q=]0,1[^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

We consider $Q= ]0,1[^2$ also $Q_1 = ]0,1[\times ]-1,1[$ and $Q_2 = ]-1,1[^2$ obtained from $Q$ by the addition of symmetrical parts.

For $p\in L^2(Q)$, we define $p_1\in \mathcal{D}'(Q_1)$ by setting
$$\forall \varphi\in\mathcal{D}(Q_1):\quad \langle p_1,\varphi\rangle = \int_Q p(x,y)[\varphi(x,y)-3\varphi(x,-y)+2\varphi(x,-y/2)]dxdy$$

I have to prove that: $p_1|_Q = p $ in $\mathcal{D}'(Q)$ and that this implies in particular that $$\|p_1\|_{L^2(Q_1)}\geq \|p\|_{L^2(Q)}.$$

My ideas:

For all $\psi\in\mathcal{D}(Q_1) $,

$$\langle p_1|_Q , \psi\rangle = \langle p_1 , \psi|_Q\rangle = \int_{Q} p(x,y)\psi|_Q(x,y)dxdy$$

If I take $\psi|_Q (x,y) = \varphi(x,y) - 3\varphi(x,-y) + 2\varphi(x,-y/2)$

So, $$ \int_{Q} p(x,y)\psi|_Q(x,y)dxdy = \int_Q p(x,y)[\varphi(x,y) - 3\varphi(x,-y) + 2\varphi(x,-y/2)]dxdy = \langle p,\psi\rangle,$$
and that this implies that $$ p_1|_Q =  p$$

To show the inequality between the $L^2$ norms, I tried the following:

$$\|p\|_{L^2(Q)} = \sup_{\|g\|_{L^2(Q)}\leq 1}|\int_Q p(x,y)g(x,y)dxdy| = \sup_{\|g\|_{L^2(Q)}\leq 1}|\int_Q p_1|_Q (x,y)g(x,y)dxdy|$$
$$\leq \sup_{\|g\|_{L^2(Q_1)}\leq 1}|\int_{Q_1} p_1|_Q (x,y)g(x,y)dxdy|\leq \|p_1\|_{L^2(Q_1)}.$$

**My Edit:**

For all $\psi\in\mathcal{D}(Q_1) $, and $p_1|_Q(x,y) = -3p(x,y)+4p(x,y)$ if $y<0$.

$$\langle p_1|_Q , \psi\rangle = \int_{Q_1} p_1|_Q(z_1,z_2)\psi(z_1,z_2)dz_1dz_2 = \int_{Q} p(z_1,z_2)\psi(z_1,z_2)dz_1dz_2 - 3\int_{Q} p(z_1,-z_2)\psi(z_1,z_2)dz_1dz_2 + 4 \int_{Q} p(z_1,-2z_2)\psi(z_1,z_2)dz_1dz_2,$$
if we use the following variable change, $y=-z_2$ and $y=-2z_2$, then
$$= \int_{Q} p(x,y)\psi(x,y)dxdy - 3\int_{Q} p(x,y)\psi(x,-y)dxdy + 2 \int_{Q} p(x,y)\psi(x,-y/2)dxdy.$$
Where the function $\varphi(x,y) = \psi(x,y) - 3\psi(x,-y) + 2\psi(x,-y/2)$ and
$$\langle p_1|_Q , \psi\rangle = \langle p, \varphi\rangle.$$
Thus, $$p_1|_Q = p.$$

Comment: What do you want to know?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout I wish to know if my ideas are correct or not. But what would be the correct steps to follow